# Eslint Parsing error: Unexpected token as when using operator 'as"

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, eslint

I can't use the typescript operator `as` in my `.vue` files, When I commit code use `lint-staged`, it show erros as below:

```js
const collapse = inject('collapse') as Ref<boolean>
// 14:36  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token as
```

```js
// eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:vue/vue3-recommended'
  ],
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['./src/**/*.ts'],
      parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
      plugins: ['@typescript-eslint']
    },
    {
      files: ['./src/**/*.vue'],
      parser: 'vue-eslint-parser'
    }
  ],
  rules: {
    'no-multiple-empty-lines': ['error', { max: 1 }],
    'vue/no-unused-vars': 'error',
    'vue/multi-word-component-names': 'off'
  }
}
```

```json
// package.json
{
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{ts,vue}": "eslint"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^17.4.4",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^17.4.4",
    "@types/node": "^18.14.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.54.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.54.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "eslint": "^8.35.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.9.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "lint-staged": "^13.1.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "sass": "^1.58.3",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7",
    "terser": "^5.16.5",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "unplugin-auto-import": "^0.15.0",
    "unplugin-vue-components": "^0.24.0",
    "vite": "^4.1.4",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.2.0"
  }
```

I try to use `babel-eslint` and `@babel/preset-typescript`, but it still not work

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the question finally by this:

```js
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:vue/vue3-recommended'
  ],
  parser: 'vue-eslint-parser',
  parserOptions: {
    parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser"
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['./src/**/*.ts'],
      parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
      plugins: ['@typescript-eslint']
    },
    {
      files: ['./src/**/*.vue'],
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).